# Обрезание строки в c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

Здравствуйте. Есть вот такая вот строка:

```
http://localhost:28381/Aggregates/4_51_StanKJ/ManualForm.aspx
```

При определённых условиях, мне нужно будет оставлять часть строки, а именно:

```
http://localhost:28381/
```

А дальше уже приклеить другой кусок текста. Как так можно сделать? Оставить именно localhost с его номером?

Comment: Почему бы не воспользоваться классом Uri?

Comment: класс [Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) для работы с адресами

Comment: @VladD просто я подумал тут есть более простой вариант отрезать ту часть строки которую мне нужно.

Comment: Важный вопрос. Это консоль, wpf, winform, asp.net или иное?

Comment: @EgorTrutnev asp.net

Comment: Более короткий, но менее надёжный. Формат адреса может быть сложным, и вы, поверьте, не хотите разбирать его вручную.

Comment: @Андрей я так понимаю, вам нужен адрес вашего же сайта, но обрезанный вариант? Собственно, увидел вашу запись про Request.Url. Как раз её и хотел предложить.

Comment: @EgorTrutnev да, вы правильно поняли.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Как подсказывают в комментариях для таких задач целесообразно использовать [класс `Uri`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) из стандартной библиотеки.

Создаем на основе строки объект `Uri`:

```
var uri = new Uri(@"http://localhost:28381/Aggregates/4_51_StanKJ/ManualForm.aspx");
```

Получаем нужную часть пути:

```
var truncUri = uri.Scheme + "://" + uri.Authority;
```

или как-то так:

```
var truncUri = uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, UriFormat.UriEscaped);
```

еще вариант:

```
var truncUri = uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
```

Comment: Спасибо, хороший вариант. Выкрутился почти так же. Только использовал Request.Url и читал нужные мне части строки. host и port соответственно.

Comment: @Андрей, верно, `Request.Url` возвращает объект этого же класса `Uri`